# adding multiple values to a key in an object js

Tags: javascript, json

My goal is to assign same color to all the events in a particular object. My object looks like :

```
var hConfig = [
                {
                    label: "A",
                    criteria: ["Event0", "Event1"],
                    field: "evt"
                },
                {
                    label: "B",
                    criteria: ["Event2", "Event3"],
                    field: "evt"
                },
                {
                    label: "C",
                    criteria: ["Event4", "Event5", "Event6"],
                    field: "evt"
                }
            ];
```

So all the criteria belonging to a label should be of same color. The function that does that is:

```
        function highlightRegex (highlightConfig) {
            // we will return an array of regex objects
            var i;
            var hl;
            for (i = 0; i < highlightConfig.length; i++) {
                hl = highlightConfig[i];
                logger.info("hl object", hl);
                hl.re = new RegExp(hl.criteria, "im");
            }
        }

            function highlight (event, highlightConfig) {
                // we will return the index if there is a match and -1 otherwise
                var i;
                var hl;
                for (i = 0; i < highlightConfig.length; i++) {
                    hl = highlightConfig[i];
                    if (hl.re.test(event[hl.field])) {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            }
```

For each data, when the event name matches the one in the criteria, we assign a color.

```
resultHighlight = highlight(value, hConfig);
value.evtColor = getColor(resultHighlight);
```

Now this works perfectly if I pass just one value for criteria key.

```
criteria: "Event1"
```

But if I have to pass multiple event names in criteria key then it breaks and does not assign color to any event names. How should I read the criteria as an array of values and make sure that it reads it correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RegeExp expects an string and not an array, you will have to make that yourself.

Kinda like that:

```
var criteriaString = '(' + hl.criteria.join(')|(') + ')';
hl.re = new RegExp(criteriaString , "im");
```

This should convert the array `["Event4", "Event5", "Event6"]` to the following string: `(Event4)|(Event5)|(Event6)`, which is regex for either Event4 or Event5 or Event6.

Comment: Yup that was an issue. This solution worked perfectly. Thanks :)